# SQL query to get records from specified months

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is data from table trail_db

```
id   | Name | months     | salary
_________________________________________
1    | abc  | April-2014 | 200.00
2    | pqr  | May-2014   | 200.00
3    | lmn  | June-2014  | 200.00
        ...
11   | cvb  | Feb-2015   | 200.00
12   | sdg  | Mar-2015   | 200.00
```

How to select records from April-2014 to Mar-2015.

I tried for query,

select * from trail_db where months between 'April-2014' and 'Mar-2015'

but it's not working properly. Which SQL query will work?...

Comment: What type is the months column?

Comment: It's varchar, because I'm inserting month with year into single column.

Comment: When I use above sql query it's not displaying records of May-2014,Sep-2014,Oct-2014,Nov-2014.. I'm not getting the error. Please help me.

Comment: Thats a bad DB design and you should store the date using mysql native datatypes `date`,`datetime` or `timestamp`

Comment: Oh..yes, Sorry, now i'll change the DB design & try again.@Abhik Chakraborty

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Select *
from trail_db 
where STR_TO_DATE(months,'%M-%Y') + 1
  between STR_TO_DATE('April-2014','%M-%Y') + 1
  and STR_TO_DATE('Mar-2015','%M-%Y') + 1
order by STR_TO_DATE(months,'%M-%Y') + 1;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43709/19)

But you shouldn't really be storing date type data in this way; it's better to store it as proper dates and extract the parts you need in the query and let the front end handle formatting.

Comment: Your query work for me, thank you.., but with some modification as  "SELECT *
FROM creche_unit_expen
WHERE STR_TO_DATE( months, '%M-%Y' )
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( 'April-2014', '%M-%Y' )
AND STR_TO_DATE( 'Mar-2015', '%M-%Y' )
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( months, '%M-%Y' )"

Comment: @VijayaSavant I tried that version too, but the str_to_date function returned the last date of every previous month which was why I added the +1. The results do seem to be the same though. See this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43709/22

Comment: @jaw, when I use your query as it is , i was getting same problem as you get after removing +1.. why this is so?. I'm working on phpmyadmin

Comment: @VijayaSavant I have no idea why MySQL does this; I guess it's by design but I didn't see anything in the manual that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your varchar into date (using format you used) and then you can compare it (otherwise comparing is lexicographic)

`"Select * from trail_db where STR_TO_DATE(months, '%M-%Y') between 'April-2014' and 'Mar-2015'";`